# Eclipse (Squish) add custom annotation types

Tags: eclipse, plugins, annotations, appearance, squish

Hay, has anybody experiences with adding custom annotation types or appearance color options to the eclipse squish IDE? I'm trying to find a way to highlight previously verbalized words in the editor (i.e. **markme_**something(parameter). Sadly I can't find any plugins and as far as I noticed squish is doing a good job to hamper any kinds of external not former installed or in the manual mentioned plugins.

Another of my thoughts are to write an addition to the syntax checker but that would be probably kinda over the top and not that easy to realize. The source code is written in python.

Greetings and thanks!
Eduard

Comment: What do you mean by "adding custom annotation types or appearance color options"?

Comment: In preferences --> Text Editors --> Annotations are different types i.e. "Break Point" or "Errors". My thought was to (probably not even possible) add a custom annotation type "markme_" which may mark/highlight in the same way as a break point/error warning would. I know about the highlighting with Ctrl + H but I tried to find a way to instantly mark the previously mentioned. I just don't think there is a reasonable way. My first thought was to add a plugin but I couldn't find any possibility to add third party plugins (beside the one in the manual). But thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

To mark a search string in the editor you can use Search > Search... (Ctrl+H). Then just enter the search string and press Enter. (While this will open and populate the "Search" view, the search string occurrences are being marked in the editor anyway.)

Perhaps you are trying to let the script editor color (a customizable set of) substrings in a customizable way? I have not found an Eclipse plug-in that would achieve that. The closest I could find (and available in source code form) is [Highlight On Selection](https://github.com/huntingriver/Eclipse-HighlightOnSelection).

PS: Note that custom plug-ins are not supported in the Squish IDE, but that you can use the [Eclipse IDE Integration](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/eclipse.ide.integration.html#eclipse.ide.integration), and then install the desired plug-ins into this Eclipse installation.